# PrimeNG checkbox not getting checked by default

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng, angular4-forms, primeng-checkbox

I have an angular project in which I am using a PrimeNG checkbox component but there is an issue when I am trying to set the checkbox's default value to checked. I even tried binding `[checked]` property but I guess it is not known to p-checkbox.

**HTML file**

```
<p-checkbox name="checkboxName" [(ngModel)]="checked" 
binary="true" label="Perform Notifications"></p-checkbox>

{{checked}}
```

**Component file**

```
export class XYZ{
checked: boolean = true;
}
```

When that gets loaded, I can see value of checked variable as 'true' below in HTML page but the checkbox is blank or unchecked.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etkqhd?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Code seems fine, Issue might be somewhere else

Comment: yeah right, i figured out that my class file was overriding the default background color from blue to white so i was not able to see the sign at first. thank you for the efforts. :)

Answer (score 6):

Following code works with Angular 8.

**HTML file**

```
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
```

**.ts file**

```
checked: boolean = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was none of the answers listed. If you have your checkbox in the middle of a form, you also have to give your checkbox a unique name to identify it within the form. For example:

```
<p-checkbox class="checkbox" name="should_renew" [(ngModel)]="myBoolean" binary="true"></p-checkbox>
```

Without the name, my checkbox was always false by default, regardless of its ngModel, and toggling it was not changing the boolean it was tied to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

In **.ts** file:

```
checked: boolean = true;
```

In **.html** file:

```
[(ngModel)]="checked"
```